# incluir servicio de windows en un proyécto vb.net

Tags: vb.net, servicio, instalacion, aplicación-escritorio

Tengo realizada una aplicación de escritorio por un lado y un servicio de windows por otro (ambos en vb.net),  es decir son dos proyectos distintos de visual studio. La pregúnta es cómo incluir el servicio de windows en la aplicación de escritorio. Puedo instalar las dos por serparado y todo funciona bien pero lo que quiero es que al instalar la aplicación de escritorio el servicio se instale automáticamente. Para hacer el paquete de instalación estoy usando advanced installer. Lo que no sé es si antes de hacer el instalador tengo que incluir el servicio en el proyecto de la aplicación de escritorio en el mismo visual studio o si agrego el servicio con el mismo advanced installer, ya que tiene la opción de incluir servicios. Traté de incluir el servicio de windows en el advanced installer pero luego de la instalación de la aplicación el servicio no corre. Desde ya agradezco a quien me pueda ayudar con ésto.